# Trying to find a good picture/diagram of SQL Server security: logins, roles, etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, security

and failing miserably.

I was trying to explain this to someone and thought it'd be easier with a nice diagram. Why bother drawing one when you have the web? Alas, I couldn't find anything that was clear enough.

If you have a link to something that clearly shows the boundaries/relationships of how it works, I'd be very grateful

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image: Diagram]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC169620.gif))</sub>

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191465(v=SQL.90).aspx

That article is available for SQL Server 2005/2008/2008R2/Denali.

I tried posting the image directly, but my rep isn't there yet.  :-)

Comment: Visually this picture is step up from the 'toilet men shaking hands on the globe' one. However, it loses the interactions. Is there some form of 'wikipedia for picture editing'? Would be great to put out something like this and have the community edit it.

Comment: I hear where you're coming from, Adolf, but SQL Server security is such a complex topic that I can't imagine trying to explain it without some prose.

Answer (score 0):

[Role-based security in SQL Server http://i.technet.microsoft.com/Cc966453.sp30102%28en-us,TechNet.10%29.gif](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/Cc966453.sp30102%28en-us,TechNet.10%29.gif)

Source: [SQL Server 2000 Security Model](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966453.aspx) from Microsoft TechNet

Comment: I had seen that one but wasn't convinced by the clarity of it. It also doesn't seem to mention logins, sql server instances or schemas (probably because the latter was a 2005 introduction)

Comment: @adolf garlic : hello sir, did you get the diagram then ? i also have the same issue. please help?

Comment: No, I'm still looking for a clear readable diagram and am astonished that no one has one.